# What is going to happen to internal references when moving to the new domain?

Tags: discussion, migration

I'm guessing that there will be some kind of massive global search/replace in the question and answer content to replace webmasters.stackexchange.com with ournewdomain.com, ensuring that inter-question (and intra-question) links are still valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the WebApps Meta site, it was said that it would be a 301 (permanent) redirect.

Comment: This is correct for *all* stack exchange beta sites. The legacy links will continue to function.

Comment: Yeah, I worded that poorly didn't I?

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that it would make the data dumps easier to work with to clean up the data, but I guess the 301s would be required anyway to deal with public beta external links.

Comment: You can always edit questions/answers with old links as and when you see them.